# Automatically Play a Google Earth Tour

Tags: kml, google-earth

Is it possible to automatically play a Google Earth tour once it is opened?

Currently you must click the `Play` button for the tour to start. If there is something I can add into the KML tour file that will make this happen or if there is something I can modify in Google Earth that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through this for 3 month, there is no such way to play a tour or  multi-track in Google earth Automatically.